# HQL query with enums

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm trying to make this query work, in my model Workshop I have a enum type field where it connects to roles.

I kinda have never used HQL to do this, only simple HQL queries, I know it's really powerful and simplifies a lot of things but whenever I try to create a query to match the enumerated role it either throws a message about "dereference".

The models corresponding this query is

- AccountRoles (enum class)
- Workshop (annotated class)
- Account (annotated class)

.

```
NamedQuery(name="namedOne", 
    query="from Workshop s inner join Account a where a.account_role = :role"
```

I have tried this one query which is probably wrong, another one like this

```
NamedQuery(name="namedOne", query="from Workshop accounts.account_role = :role"
```

The field accounts contains

```
@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name="links_ws2accounts")
public List<models.ws.Account> accounts = new ArrayList<models.ws.Account>();
```

Any suggestion is appreciated, if you need a bit more info let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is not very clear, but I guess the query should look like this:

```
from Workshop s inner join s.accounts a where a.account_role = :role
```

Comment: It works man! Thanks, I was having problem with creating the query, I thought it was just "go along the paths" without the inner join (expected it to do it automatic). Cheers